# Can I use Gradle to build a classpath string

Tags: gradle

I need to execute an external Java application as part of a Gradle build process. The external application needs the same JARs in its classpath as the application Gradle is building. Is there any way to expose the dependencies I have defined in Gradle to the external application?

i.e. I need to run this:

> `java -jar -cp [jars from Gradle] myapp.jar`

Comment: Can You please clarify the scenario a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a simple task to your build to get the resulting classpath.

```
task printClasspath << {
    println configurations.runtime.asPath
}
```